# Can PayPal transfer money between users?

Tags: api, paypal, transfer, currency

I am building an app in which user A pays user B for a service while also paying Company C an intermediate fee. Does PayPal offer this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you make look into PayPal Adaptive Payments:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/